# Some mobile clients are unable to connect to UniFi AP mysteriously

Tags: routing, router, wireless, dhcp, networking

We have two UniFi Controllers, one contains the main internet its directly connected to the fibre and then we give internet to the second controller using LAN connection, internet works fine in main controller but on the second controller which has 4 wireless networks, it sometimes gets connected and sometimes it does not even let the device connected in wireless it says Access Denied or sometimes tries to connect and then comes back.

I'm really new to networking and all that stuff i have attached. Logs in PNG. Here are a few technical stuff i can explain:

Main Unifi Controller ==>

```
WAN:

Router: 192.168.1.1

Subnet : /24

DHCP Mode Enabled:

DHCP gateway: 192.168.1.1

DNS: 1.1.1.1

DNS2: 1.0.0.1

domain: our.server

Wireless:

Radius EAP Auth enabled which authenticates clients to our NPAS in Windows server.

LAN:

Static IP: 192.168.1.250 (Assigned by our ISP the guy who setup the first router)

So internet works a but fine on laptop from all the wireless AP in the main Controller.

Now in the second Controller

WAN:

Router: 192.168.2.1 (This second controller)

Subnet : /24

DHCP Mode Enabled:

DHCP gateway: 192.168.2.1

DNS: 1.1.1.1

DNS2: 1.0.0.1

domain: our.server

Wireless:

WPA with key

LAN:

Static IP: 192.168.1.250 (Since Ip is being assigned by DHCP in Controller 1 via the LAN) .
```

The issue is mainly in the second controller's Wireless:

I have assigned static channels based on a forum here at UI.

**Access Denied
Cannot Connect
Disabled**

These are the messages we get while connecting mobiles to our wireless AP from the second controller.

I'm really new so maybe someone can help.

[image: system config]

[image: networkconfig]

Thanks!

Regards

**UPDATE: I have turned of CCMP encryption and now on TKIP mode clients can connect.**

Comment: "I have turned of CCMP encryption and now on TKIP mode clients can connect." -> those mobile clients didn't support CCMP but could use TKIP. But TKIP is actually not as secure. May be better if you could upgrade the devices instead?

Comment: these are latest phones, Huawei, Samsung, etc. I don't know why they does not support 802.11i on CCMP.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have turned of CCMP encryption and now on TKIP mode, clients can connect.
TKIP itself is weak i don't know why CCMP is not accepted by latest gen smartphones.